# Using post_where filter only on main query NOT sidebard new WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, filters

I have a post where filter set up for a CPT archive page.  Which works great but i have other WP_Query objects in the sidebar that dont work because the post_where filter is effecting those Objects too.  How can i get the filter to only work on the main page and not the sidebar?

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'Where_Events', 10, 1);
function Where_Events($where)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $current_date = new DateTime('now');
    $current_month = $current_date->format('m');
    $current_year = $current_date->format('Y');

$query_month = get_query_var( 'eventMonth', $current_month );
$query_year = get_query_var( 'eventYear', $current_year );
$query_day = '01';
$query_date = $query_year .'-'. $query_month . '-' . $query_day;

// check date where function
//default return current month
if (! is_admin() && (is_post_type_archive('gnl_events') && is_main_query())) {
    $where .= ' AND MONTH(events_occurence) = MONTH("'.$query_date.'")';
    $where .= ' AND YEAR(events_occurence) = YEAR("'.$query_date.'")';
}
return $where;
```

}

Comment: I got it to work by removing the filter before the new WP_Query in the sidebar.. and readded the filter after, but not sure if that is the best/only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter here would be useful in targeting the appropriate context.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'Where_Events', 10, 2  );
function Where_Events( $where, $wp_query ) { }
```

The global `$wp_query` would be able to tell you whether the query was for the main query by checking `$wp_query->is_main_query()`.

Comment: that worked... thank you!